# How to write this in jquery slider

Tags: jquery

Im trying to write some jquery code that will help me
I need a slider
can sum1 help me pls
THANK U
I tried this but it didn't work

```
$(slider).appendTo('html')

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=html name=slider>slider here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

edit: I try this but it no working as well

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"; />
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider();
});
</script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=html name=slider>slider here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did but it didn't work

Comment: u r missing jqueryui.css

Comment: Try include jQuery library than use. `$(slider).appendTo($('#html'))`

Comment: the above code is wrong..check my code I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

ref jquery.js and jqueryui.js and jqueryui.css files into ur html..http://jqueryui.com/slider/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test slider</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
           <script>
              $(function() {
              $( "#html" ).slider();
               });
              </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="html"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: how to ref jqueryui.css

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

Answer (score 0):

Accessing DOM by ID should be as below:

```
$(slider).appendTo('#html')
```

Keep attributes between apostophes:

```
<div id='html'>slider here</div>
```